# How to know when all the event handlers finished executing?

Tags: c#, events

I'm creating some tests that includes check that a method associated to an event is being executed at certain conditions. To check that the handler is executed I'm adding a sleep (x ms) to be sure that the handler has finished the execution before check the result.

Is there any way to subscribe to something that tells me when all the handlers of an event finished executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are invoked sequentially. So, subscribe to the event itself: your own handler will be called immediately after all already subscribed handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `Interlocked` and a `ManualResetEvent` if you know the number of handlers/events ahead of time.

At the start of the test, store the number of handlers and set up the event:

```
int noOfHandlers = 3; //or however many
ManualResetEvent handlersFinishedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Then in your event handler method:

```
public void OnEvent(EventArgs e)
{
    // do event stuff
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref noOfHandlers) == 0))
    {
        // only the last handler will come in here
        handlersFinishedEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Then your test thread simply waits on the `ManualResetEvent`, which will only be triggered once all events are complete:

```
handlersFinishedEvent.WaitOne();
```